# How to add multiple options to json_encode function by condition?

Tags: php

It's ok:

```
$data = json_encode(
    $data,
    JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
);
```

I want to do like that:

```
$options = "JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE";
if ($pretty) $options .= " | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT";
$data = json_encode(
    $data,
    $options
);
```

But this doesn't work because $options isn't a string or array.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is not Bash. Code and strings are orthogonal concepts.

`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` and `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` are integers.
The `|` operator joins the two integer bitmasks.
So to join them you should just `$options |= JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, and should not use quotes.

```
$options = JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE;
if ($pretty) $options |= JSON_PRETTY_PRINT;
$data = json_encode(
    $data,
    $options
);
```